# How do I edit the rules in an already created geodatabase topology in ArcGIS (10.7.1)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 with an Advanced license and created a topology for a file geodatabase I'm working with. (I have complete access to the data.) I'd like to edit the rules that I've created, but when I try to edit them via the Rules tab in the Layer Properties dialog for the topology layer in ArcMap, all of the options (Add Rule, Remove Rule, etc.) are greyed out except for Save Rules and Description. (See attached screenshot).

Is there a way to edit the geodatabase topology without removing it and starting a new one?

[image: screenshot of layer properties dialog]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify whether this is a file or Enterprise geodatabase, and what your level of access is to the data.

Comment: Updated to reflect that this is a file geodatabase that I have complete access to (i.e. it's on my local machine and I created/own it). Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Advanced/ArcInfo. Thanks for the question, and I updated the original post as well.

Comment: I'll add that I've tried this both during an edit session and out of an editing session, with the same resulting greyed out options.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, and I had to force quit a bunch of arc processes. I'm not sure which had it hung up, but it was locked.  Try a force quit on all your esri processes, or possibly a reboot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).